# При выборе select у других сбрасываем на по умолчанию, но не работает

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет, при выборе select должен выбираться первый option со значением value="0", я использую плагин https://github.com/vestman/Select-or-Die для стилизации select, если его отключить то скрипт срабатывает, подскажите как их подружить или переписать скрипт, чтобы заработало?

Стилизацию Select or Die запускаю так

```
jQuery("select").selectOrDie({
    customClass: "custom",
    customID:    "custom"
});
```

Это сортировка Isotope при помощи select, с ней отлично работает

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  // init Isotope
  var $grid = jQuery('.isotopes').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.element-item'
  });

  // store filter for each group
  var filters = {};

  jQuery('.filters').on('change', '.filters-select', function(){
    var $this = jQuery(this);
    var filterGroup = $this.attr('data-filter-group');
    filters[ filterGroup ] = $this.val();
    var filterValue = concatValues( filters );
    $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
    $this.closest('.filters').find('select').not($this).val(0);
  });

  // flatten object by concatting values
  function concatValues( obj ) {
    var value = '';
    for ( var prop in obj ) {
      value += obj[ prop ];
    }
    return value;
  }
});
```

Вот эта часть, что делаю

```
$this.closest('.filters').find('select').not($this).val(0);
```

Должно работать так

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('select').on('change', function() {
    $(this).closest('.filters').find('select').not($(this)).val(0);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filters">
<select name="one" id="one">
<option value="0">Выбрать</option>
<option value="1">один</option>
<option value="2">два</option>
</select>
<select name="two" id="two">
<option value="0">Выбрать</option>
<option value="1">один</option>
<option value="2">два</option>
</select>
<select name="three" id="three">
<option value="0">Выбрать</option>
<option value="1">один</option>
<option value="2">два</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Заранее всем признателен за помощь!